# Optimal distribution using KKT condition

Tags: probability, convex-optimization, self-learning, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have following problem 
\begin{eqnarray}
&\min_{p,t}&\quad \sum_{i =1}^n \frac{a_i^2}{p_i} \\
&s.t.&  \sum_{i =1}^n p_i = b \\
&& 0 \leq p_i \leq 1\quad \forall i 
\end{eqnarray}
$a_i$'s are given positive parameters and b is a positive number less than $n$.
Its Hessian is $2*\text{diag}\left(\frac{a_i}{p_i^3}\right)$ thus this problem is convex, thus KKT conditions leads to the optimal solution, but I can't solve them.
Here are KKT conditions

$$
L(p,y,\lambda_1, ..,\lambda_n, u_1,...,u_n) = \sum_{i =1}^n \frac{a_i^2}{p_i} - \sum_{i =1}^n \lambda_ip_i - \sum_{i =1}^n u_i(1-p_i) + y\left(\sum_{i =1}^n p_i - b\right)\\
u_i \geq 0 \\
u_i(1-p_i) = 0 \\
\lambda_ip_i = 0\\
0 \leq p_i \leq 1 \\
-\sum_{i =1}^n \frac{a_i^2}{p_i^2} -\lambda_i + u_i + y = 0 \quad \forall i \\
  \sum_{i =1}^n p_i = b. 
$$
Does anybody know, how to solve it?

Comment: Let $A = \sum_j a_j$. If $b \leq \frac{A}{a_i}$, $\forall i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$, then a solution of the KKT system is $p_i = \frac{a_i}{A} b$, $u_i = 0$, $y = \left(\frac{A}{b}\right)^2$, $\lambda_i = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalizing my comment, here is how you can find a solution to the KKT system.

W.L.O.G., let $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \cdots \leq a_n$. Let $A_m := \sum_{i=1}^{m}{a_i}$, and $B_m := \frac{A_m}{a_m}$.

Find (the largest) $k \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ such that $0 < b - (n-k) \leq B_k$ (note that $k$ is well-defined; under the condition proposed in my comment, we have $k = n$). Then $$p_i = \frac{a_i}{A_k} \left[b - (n-k)\right], \:\: i = 1,\cdots,k,$$ $$p_{k+1} = \cdots = p_n = 1,$$ $$\lambda_i = 0, \:\: \forall i,$$ $$u_1 = \cdots = u_k = 0,$$ and $u_{k+1},\cdots,u_n,y$ such that $$y = \left(\frac{A_k}{b - (n-k)}\right)^2$$ and $$u_j + y = a^2_j, \:\: j = k+1,\cdots,n,$$ solves the KKT system (note that the last system is not inconsistent with $u_i \geq 0$).